# Bootstrap sonarqube with Qulity Gates and Quality Profiles

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-plugin, quality-gate

I am trying to create sonarqube with docker-compose, one of the requirements to include quality profiles and quality gates to be available, once bring up the server by using `docker-compse up` command readily to the developers.

Is there a possibility to add quality gates and quality profiles to include in the below compose file

```
version: "2"

services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:8.8.0-community
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    environment:
      SONAR_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD: sonar
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
      - sonarqube_temp:/opt/sonarqube/temp
  db:
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: sonar
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sonar
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

networks:
  sonarnet:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_logs:
  sonarqube_temp:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
```